# Communication errors with Amazon SWF - Ruby Flow

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services

We are having an issue with the new Ruby-Flow wrapper for the Amazon SWF.

The issue is that Workflow and Activity workers will (several times an hour) be unable to correctly communicate with the SWF server. This manifests in various ways:

- workflows or activities fail to register when workers for new versions are started
- workflow or activity workers will crash
- activity workers will finish a task and then get an error when reporting that they are done, so the entire execution fails.

For worker crashes (either kind), we see the following:

```
andy@Andy-MBP:Crucible $RAILS_ENV=development rake crucible:swf:ingress_wf_start
rake aborted!
execution expired
/Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3/gems/aws-sdk-1.11.1/lib/aws/core/http/connection_pool.rb:301:in `start_session'
/Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3/gems/aws-sdk-1.11.1/lib/aws/core/http/connection_pool.rb:125:in `session_for'
/Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3/gems/aws-sdk-1.11.1/lib/aws/core/http/net_http_handler.rb:52:in `handle'
/Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3/gems/aws-sdk-1.11.1/lib/aws/core/client.rb:238:in `block in make_sync_request'
```

When the failure involves failing to update the server that a task was finished, the backtrace is pretty similar.

This doesn't seem to be an SWF issue per se (that is, it's not a timeout on the activity execution); it's a Ruby HTTP communication issue.  There are similar issues on SO for communicating with the Twitter API.

Again, it's not an issue with an SWF timeout expiring; the workflow has a timeout of a day and each activity has a timeout of an hour.  The failures occur well within that boundary.

Unfortunately, it mostly works, I can usually start workflow executions, I just get this sort of error frequently enough that that we cannot finish anything other than trivial jobs.  The errors are random enough that troubleshooting is extremely difficult.

We have reproduced this on different machines and from different networks.  We're still trying out the SWF in development, so none of the failing workers are located on EC2 instances.

---

Is there an underlying cause that I should investigate?
Is there a pattern or setting that will allow me to retry these communications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discussed this issue at some length with the Amazon person who maintains the ruby-flow library.  That discussion may be found [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-flow-ruby/issues/4).

The issue is that our computers were unable to open a connection to the AWS servers.  Setting the retry count obscenely high has addressed the issue for our development purposes.

The root cause seems to be something in Mac OSX.  We use that for development and saw this time out issue on several different machines (running 10.7 and 10.8).

A fresh Linux machine did not exhibit the problem.